# Bind WebAPI properties without action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

A lot of our Web API action patterns have the following pattern:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDetails(Guid customerGuid)
{
    Customer customer = customerRetriever.FromGuid(customerGuid);

    if (customer == null)
        return NotFound();

    // Do Stuff....
}
```

I want to move all the customer lookup boiler plate out of the action method. I created an action filter attribute to do this, by looking at the value of the action argument and setting a request property:

```
KeyValuePair<String, Object> argument = actionContext.ActionArguments.Single(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(ParameterName));
Guid customerGuid = (Guid)argument.Value;
// Do customer lookup, return 404 if needed
// Add customer to request properties
```

This works, but i still need to include the now redundant Guid in my action signature. If i remove this, my approach for finding the Guid value fails. Is there a way to bind a value from the URI, without having that value as an action parameter?

Comment: is the customer id the id if the user making the call? or is the user making a call to view a particular customer? If the former then that is what authentication and authorization action filters are for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass customerGuid as queryString parameter like `http://localhost:61374/api/values?customerGuid=D09584F2-0B81-4855-8F33-567F4EF8096C`
 Then you can fetch query string value in action filter as:

```
  public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var queryStringValues = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        var customerGuid = queryStringValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "customerGuid").Value;
        //Your logic
    }
}
```

Now there is no need to specify params in API method

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDetails()
{
  //Do stuff
}
```